# jQuery AJAX not evaluating JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have an array which i can see in the console.log(response) which is:

```
{"status":"success","message":"Success! You will get an email shortly, please confirm your email address and you will then recieve your 50% discount coupon a few days before launch!"}
```

My AJAX is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/store-address.php',
    data: 'ajax=true&email=' + escape($('#email').val()),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response.message);
        if(response.status == "success"){                               
            $('#note').html(response.message);
        }
    }
});
```

however the console.log .status and .message returns undefined. Im most likely missing something simple here but if anyone can spot why would be great

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you do console.log(response) does it spit out a json object or a string? Try using the result of JSON.parse(response) perhaps?

Comment: Ahh yes comes as an Object { status="success", message="Success! You will get a...few days before launch!"}

Answer (score 1):

Add `dataType: 'json'`

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON
>   is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty
>   response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null
>   or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON
>   formatting.)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/store-address.php',
    data: 'ajax=true&email=' + escape($('#email').val()),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response.message);
        if(response.status == "success"){                               
            $('#note').html(response.message);
        }
    },
    dataType: 'json' //Add this
```

});

Comment: Super worked a treat, new i was missing something stupid! sorry about that but thanks again.